# Applying a list of values as predicate using Collection Utils by the use of pedicates

Tags: java, apache, guava, predicate

I want to implement Database systems in functionality by using the predicate.

This is as like if SQL filter a recordset by in it cumbersome the results.

But if i pass the List as in predicate it takes only one value i.e. if i am passing 53 and 54 it filter the results for 53 only.

```
public class classNamePredicate implements Predicate<className> {
private Object expected1;
private String property;
private List<Object> listOfValues = new ArrayList<Object>();

public SalesOrderPredicate(Object expected1, String property) {
    super();
    this.expected1 = expected1;
    this.property = property;
}

public SalesOrderPredicate(List<Object> listValues, String property) {
    this.listOfValues = listValues;
    this.property = property;
}

@Override
public boolean evaluate(SalesOrder object) {
    try {
        if (property.equals("volume")) {
            return ((Integer) expected1 < object.getVolume());
        }
        if (property.equals("startDateId")) {
            return (expected1.equals(object.getStartDateId()));
        }
        if (property.equals("endDateId")) {
            return (expected1.equals(object.getEndDateId()));
        }
        if (property.equals("productIds")) {
            for (Object value : listOfValues) {
                return (object.getProductId() == (Integer) value);
            }
        }
        if (property.equals("sourceIds")) {
            for (Object value : listOfValues) {
                return (object.getSourceId() == (Integer) value);
            }
        }
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

I am trying to use this as per the following way:

```
List<Object> productIds = new ArrayList<Object>();
        productIds.add(53);
        productIds.add(54);

        List<Object> sourceIds = new ArrayList<Object>();
        sourceIds.add(122);

Predicate[] classnameOrderPredicate = { (Predicate) new classnamePredicate(4415, "startDateId"),
                (Predicate) new classnamePredicate(4443, "endDateId"), (Predicate) new classnamePredicate(100000, "volume"),
                (Predicate) new classnamePredicate(productIds, "productIds"), (Predicate) new classnamePredicate(sourceIds, "sourceIds") };
        Predicate classnameallPredicateGeneric = (Predicate) PredicateUtils
                .allPredicate((org.apache.commons.collections4.Predicate<? super classname>[]) classnamePredicate);

        Collection<classname> classnamefilteredCollectionGeneric = GenericCollectionUtils.select(classname, classnameallPredicateGeneric);
```

Please suggest in design perspective too.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you make your question clear? With code example may be? It is impossible to understand what you want/do

Comment: Some code is needed here; it is unclear what you want.

Comment: let me add the code..

Comment: @BITSSANDESH where do u see guava here? And make a SHORT explanation of what you what to achieve and what is not working.

Comment: @Eugene currently i am using Apache Collection4, which quite a same API alike guava, and I am seeking a design for Implementing SQL in functionality to filter a same value to be filter. Currently what happening if i am passing List<Interger> productIds with 53 and 54 but still i am getting the result of only 53.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only evaluating the first item in the collection:

```
for (Object value : listOfValues) {
    return (object.getProductId() == (Integer) value);
}
```

You want to evaluate all of them, and Java conveniently provides a `contains()` method for that:

```
return listOfValues.contains(object.getProductId());
```

---

Other than that, the code looks pretty awful, you should create smaller, targeted `Predicate`s, instead of writing a generic one with lots of different cases. You could get rid of those casts at the same time.

You also failed at your obfuscation by failing to replace a few `SalesOrder` by `className` (which doesn't respect the Java coding standard and is distracting).

Comment: thanks a lot I can't vote up the answer (Due to a less reputation). I am delight to get the review feedback, my intention to have if else condition to have less classes of predicates. As we are using POJO's for data interchange.